# How to iterate through data table pick values to pass through as a json request

Tags: java

I am writing an automation test and what I am trying to do is through each row in the dataTable, check each column and if the value does not equal "", then put the field name (coulmn name) and its value in the body to pass through as a json request.

For example:

```
|colour|food |
|      |pizza|
|red   |     |
```

So when it iterates through the first row, it should create a json body of below for first request:

```
"food":"pizza"
```

For second row it will create json body of below for second request.

```
"color":"red"
```

At the moment what is happening is that for the first request it is not passing anything and for the second request it is passing:

```
"food":"pizza"
```

I almost have it but need assistance on what I am doing wrong.

Below is the code:

```
public void testMethod(final Table table) {
    final RequestHeaders headers = Test.getCurrentHeaders();
    final Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();

    table.getColumnNames().forEach(columnName -> {

                final String value = table.getTableRows().get(0).getCell(columnName);

                    if (!value.equals("")) {
                        body.put(columnName, value);
                    }

        postRequest("/test/endpoint", headers.getMap(), SerializationHelper.asString(body));

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem might be with `table.getTableRows().get(0)` which I think always return the first row. You would have to iterate over all rows, until you find something or complete your iteration. Then you either have a value or not.

**PSEUDO**:

```java
table.getColumnNames().forEach(columnName -> {

                String value = "";
                //iterate over table rows until you are through
                for (TableRow row in table.getTableRows()){
                    value = row.getCell(columnName);
                    //if you find a value for columnName which isn't empty save it and break
                    if (!value.equals("")) {
                        body.put(columnName, value);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //we have to check whether we set a new value, before posting
                if(!value.equals("")){
                    postRequest("/test/endpoint", headers.getMap(), SerializationHelper.asString(body));
                }
    });
```

Currently As I understand it, you are iterating over the tableHeaders from left to right.

So first run will be `columnName = "colour"`

The you are getting the first row (`|      |pizza|`) and select the cell for the columnName.
The cell for columnName = colour is empty. So you skip it

Then you post the body.

Then in the second run, `columnName = "food"`

You still get the first row (`|      |pizza|`) and select the cell for the columnName.

This time the cell for columnName = food is not empty, so you put the value into the body and post it.